# Error - <a href Does not Work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The following code has a line that contains,

```
<a href="mysite.com">Sign Up</a>
```

This text we are trying to link does not work when clicked, it is linked, just not clickable.  It only doesn't work when we

```
<ng-include src=
```

to include it on our index, it works when going to the page containing just the following.  Does anyone know why?  I've NEVER had this issue.  Thanks so much!

```
<div class="header" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="welcome pull-right" ng-show="userLoaded">
  <span ng-show="currentUser">Welcome, @{{currentUser.username}}! <a href ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></span>
  <span ng-hide="currentUser"><a href ng-click="showLogin(true)">Log In</a> or 
  HERE---->  <a href="mysite.com">Sign Up</a> </span>

</div>
</div>




<div class="well" ng-show="loginVisible">
<form>
  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="username" />
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" ng-model="password" />
  <div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="login()">Log in</button>
    <button class="btn-link" ng-click="showLogin(false)">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you site should be there with protocol like `http://` or `https://` simply change anchor something like this `<a href="http://example.com">Sign Up</a>`

Comment: So, does currentUser exist? If so, that line won't appear.

Comment: @PankajParkar  Thanks for the response!  That didn't change anything, any other ideas?  We can copy the link from the text, but when we click on the linked text, nothing happens.  Thanks again!

Comment: @rrd I'm not sure what you mean.  Log in appears, and the SIgn Up texts appears with the link, but when you click it, nothing happens.   Thanks!